# Matplotlib "Zoom to rectangle" doesn't zoom well on a thin rectangle

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When you plot this 1000x1000 square:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
A = np.random.random((1000,1000))
plt.imshow(A)
plt.show()
```

[image]

then click on `Zoom to rectangle` and select a thin rectangle, the output is "not very zoomed":

[image]

**This is probably because it tries to keep the aspect ratio; how to disable this, and have a zoom that uses all the available space in the maplotlib GUI window?**

Comment: Do you only want to change aspect ratio when you zoom?

Comment: If the aspect ratio of the original image doesn't matter then simply use `plt.imshow(A, aspect="auto")`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @DavidG,

```
plt.imshow(A, aspect="auto")
```

solves it:

[image]